# Access a control on the particular Content Page from a MasterPage using JavaScript

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net I took one master page and one Web Form selected with the master page.
In first web form i have one textbox and button.
When button click then OnClientClick property contains validate() function 
Now In master page's coding I written as following :

```
    function validate() {
        var no = document.getElementById('<%=Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("TextBox1").ClientID %>').value;
        if (isNaN(no)) {
            alert('not a number.');
        }
    }
```

Now i took second web form
In that i put one calendar control and just run it 
error occurs as following :

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Line 11:         function validate() {
Line 12:             var no = document.getElementById('<%=Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("TextBox1").ClientID %>').value;
Line 13:             if (isNaN(no)) {
Line 14:                 alert('not a number.');

I am seeing Line 12 : as a red line.

So How to run this second Web Form

Answer (score 0):

Inside content page declare an in-line Javascript variable.

```
<script>
  var jsTextBox1Id = <%=TextBox1.ClientID%>;
</script>
```

Now you can access the control ID in `Validate()` using global `jsTextBox1Id` variable.
Like this:

```
  var no = document.getElementById(jsTextBox1Id).value;
```

*(Remember this type of approach is not a recommended practice.)*

### Update

To get a reference to the HTML element that is rendered for any control in client script, you must know the value of the control's **ClientID** property. However, because the user control can be put anywhere in a Web page, it is impossible to know in advance which naming containers will contain the controls. To make sure that the **ClientID** value will be the same as the **ID** value, the just set the **ClientIDMode** value to **Static**.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyStaticId" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Now you can access it using the ID defined by you `MyStaticId`, it will not have prepended parent container name to it.

```
 document.getElementById("MyStaticId").value
```

[Source MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.. It works as second form runs. But alert message not appears in first web form as user types non numeric value. so validation is not done. But it is possible ? -- without writing any script code in content page and direct any code write in master page so also it works.

Comment: I write the following code for textbox                    <asp:TextBox ID="MyStaticId" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>                                                     and in masterpage i write following code :                         function validate() {
        //var no = document.getElementById("MyStaticId").value;
        var no = document.getElementById("MyStaticId").innerHTML;
        if (isNaN(no)) {
            alert('not a number.');
        }
    }                                                            But it not works..

Comment: Did you looked at the ID in the source of page rendered in browser ?

Comment: sorry, what you are telling I do not understand ?

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: You can view the HTML source of page using Developer tools provided in browser. Use it to see the Id of textbox and the JS error.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector